# Distinguishing between private and public classes/api in ios at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-privateapi

I am finding the view hierarchy of one of the view in iOS Application. When i was parsing the view hierarchy(by using command view.superview in loop and printing the view description), i got many objects of the private classes like

```
UILayoutContainerView 
UIViewControllerWrapperView
UINavigationTransitionView
UITableViewCellScrollView
UITableViewCellContentView
```

Now, I want to distinguish that which of them are private and which are public, so that i can use the public one(so, that my app will not get rejected by apple).

Comment: You have still not edited your question to say programmatically.

Comment: Trying to do this at runtime is a very poor design.  Very poor.

Answer (score 1):

A class (or method) belongs to a public API when it is documented in the official, public Apple documentation. If you're generous you could say that classes (and methods) in the SDK header files are also public, even if they are not explicitly documented. But as you can see, the information whether a given class (or method) belongs to a public or private API is not something that is encoded anywhere in the runtime. This means that, regardless of any introspection capabilities of Objective-C, it is simply impossible to achieve what you want.

The only way how you can get a solution that *approximates* what you want is to somehow encode and store the desired information yourself. You can store the information in your app (essentially hard-coding it), or you could even go as far as querying your server for the information. But as you probably have realized yourself, neither of these schemes is elegant, and moreover you will be very busy updating the information with every new version of iOS.

I suggest you take the time and rethink your app design.

Answer (score 0):

This method takes a view and compares its class, as an NSString, with an array of all of the public UIView subclasses, also as NSStrings, and returns YES if the view's class is public.  If applicable, you will have to include your own custom UIView subclasses in the array as well.

```
-(BOOL)isViewPublic:(UIView *)view {
    static NSArray *publicClasses;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        publicClasses = @[@"UIView",
                          @"UIWindow",
                          @"UILabel",
                          @"UIPickerView",
                          @"UIProgressView",
                          @"UIActivityIndicatorView",
                          @"UIImageView",
                          @"UITabBar",
                          @"UIToolBar",
                          @"UINavigationBar",
                          @"UITableViewCell",
                          @"UIActionSheet",
                          @"UIAlertView",
                          @"UIScrollView",
                          @"UISearchBar",
                          @"UIWebView",
                          @"UIControl",
                          @"UITableView",
                          @"UITextView",
                          @"UIButton",
                          @"UIDatePicker",
                          @"UIPageControl",
                          @"UISegmentedControl",
                          @"UITextField",
                          @"UISlider",
                          @"UISwitch"];
    });
    for (NSString *publicClass in publicClasses) {
        if ([publicClass isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass([view class])]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: i need general method, this only scans that which are in privateClasses array, i have just posted 3-4 names only for description

Comment: @MehulThakkar than add every single Private class to that array then because that is the only way and that is just insane to check for every single class as there are hundreds if not thousands.

Comment: @Popeye: Yes, that will be the idea, but it will be the last approach that can be used, because, i think, there must be some another generalized approach to do that

Comment: @MehulThakkar there is no generalized approach because you have no need to check. Every developer can get away without checking them so why are you wanting to check them unless you are wanting to use them.

Comment: @JustinMoser: What if there is any customized class is there in hierarchy, so, listing the public classes is not good approach, i.e for example if i have subclassed the UIButton with name xyzButton, in that case, xyzButton in public class, still it will not be in list of public classes

Comment: "If applicable, you will have to include your own custom UIView subclasses in the array as well."

Answer (score 0):

Use this dev tool, [App Scanner](http://www.chimpstudios.com/). It scans your .app file for private API methods. A future release will also check for private API instance variables. and you can also use **otool** for detect private api

Comment: i need to check that at runtime, App Scanner will check it compile time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately they are all private so you can't use any of them.

For a list of the all the private APIs have a look at [iPhone Private Frameworks](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/tree/master/UIKit).

All of those are covered under [iPhone Private Frameworks UIKit](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/tree/master/UIKit)

Comment: I know this things, but i want to check it programmatically that given api is private or not.

Comment: @MehulThakkar you want to check at runtime for every single private API??? You're going to have to write something to check for every private API in that case because you might have something returned that isn't in that list and that is just insane. And you don't say you want to do it programmatically you need to make this clear in your question. Why do you even what that?? Evey other developer can get away without actually using any of them so why can't you.

Comment: Yes, i want to do it runtime, i mean want to check for each single private api that will be in myView's view hierarchy

Comment: Is there any way by which i can just get the view hierarchy that is implemented by me in xib or programmatically(avoiding private/extra objects that are made by ios by it own)

Comment: If you look through that link for the UIKit you will see there are well over a hundred classes that could be in there and you want to check all of them? That is insane. A view is constructed from many private classes, why do you even want to check for them anyway? You don't know the method names on them so there isn't really a way to call one accidentally so unless you are actually wanting call them yourself you don't need to do anything to check them it will just waste memory and slow your app right down.

Comment: i am sending some data from server, and based on that data, whole navigation etc of view is going to be rendered on screen. Now, i want to store the whole view hierarchy in database, but in this view hierarchy, i dont want this private stuff, i just want to remove that out.

Comment: Well I believe your first issue is the rendering of the UI based on what the server is saying. If I remember rightly Apple don't like this because you could submit one app for review then change it completely after successfully getting through the app store review process.